# How would I import a single column CSV file into a pie chart using Javascript D3?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Hopefully I can explain myself properly, as I am new to JS, but I need to import a CSV file as the data for a pie chart. My csv file is just a single column, with the header "Type", and the values are not all the same. There's three types: Mediumn, Low, High and theres 63 values in total.

What I'm doing currently is d3.csv("types.csv"). After this step, I don't know how to get it to read the data as 3 seperate values. So, how would I go about doing this? Can I get it to iterate over the object array and increment an empty array and get the pie chart to use that as the data? Pseudo code example:
var types = {}
foreach type
+1 types
to end up with
var types = {Low: 2, Medium: 4, High: 10}
and then parse that into the pie chart.

Hope I make sense! :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`d3.rollup`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group), which reduces groups into a value, and returns an [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map).

```
d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, d => d.type)
//              reducer       grouper
```

`d3.rollup` will **reduce** any group with the specified reducer: the **groups** are determined by the grouper function.

We group with `d => d.type`, so any values that have the same type are in the same group. After grouping, you'd have an `Map` that looks like this:

```js
d3.group(data, d => d.type) 
== 
Map(3) {
  "High" => Array(1) // of objects
  "Medium" => Array(2)
  "Low" => Array(4)
}
```

Afterwards, we reduce each group, here with `v => v.length`. d3 takes each group (each `Map`) we have just created and applies that function, converting the array to a value. Here it will take the length of each group: for the Low group, it'll return 4 since there are four entries in the group.

```js
const data = d3.csvParse(`type,value
Medium,7,2
Medium,5
Low,0.2
Low,3.4
High,2
Low,1
Low,1`)

const grouped =
  d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, d => d.type)
  
console.log("Low:",    grouped.get("Low"))
console.log("Medium:", grouped.get("Medium"))
console.log("High:",   grouped.get("High"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```